# Multiple callback on $.get

Tags: jquery, get

here is the code :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get("realisations.shtml",function(data){$('#realisations').empty().append(data)});
    });
</script>
```

I need to execute $(".toexpand").hide(); after beeing sure the data is loaded into the div

this try dont work :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get("realisations.shtml",function(data){$('#realisations').empty().append(data)},function(){$(".toexpand").hide()});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need to have multiple callbacks, but simply execute multiple statements in your single callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("realisations.shtml",function(data) {
        $('#realisations').empty().append(data);
        $(".toexpand").hide();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("realisations.shtml",function(data) { 
       $('#realisations').empty().append(data);
       $(".toexpand").hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

is there a reason you aren't using $().load() ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#realisations').load("realisations.shtml", function() {
        $(".toexpand").hide();
    });
});
```